# Updating WWW::Curl::Easy to work with TLS

Tags: perl, libcurl, tls1.2

I'm trying to update a simple Perl subroutine that lets our program connect with Brazil's government's servers to upload invoices. It works fine today, as shown below:

```
use WWW::Curl::Easy;
my $curl = WWW::Curl::Easy->new;
my $response_body;

my @param = ('Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8', "SOAPAction: '$action''");
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, "$urlsefaz"); # one of Brazil's SEFAZ URLs
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_PORT , 443);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_SSLCERT, "$certificate");
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_SSLKEY, "$privateKey");
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, \@param);
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,\$response_body);

my $responsexml = $curl->perform;
```

However, Brazil's government updated their security policy, and for their next update they won't accept SSLv3 connections anymore, only accepting TLS 1.2 instead, which is causing my current connection attempts with the new test servers to fail.

According to the [MetaCPAN Documentation on WWW::Curl](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Curl), which includes an example for WWW::Curl::Easy, the method `setopt` should take "most" `libcurl` parameters. I belive it is taking the `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION` correctly, but instead of taking one of the constants described in [CURLOPT_SSLVERSION's documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSLVERSION.html), the programmer who did this bit of code decided to inform the equivalent value to one of the options (presumably SSLv3) instead?

So, I have no clue as to what value should I pass to `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION` to inform this module to work with TLS 1.2, or how to inform the correct constant instead. Or is there another `setopt` argument that I could set for it to work with TLS 1.2?

Also, if there's no workaround, I'm considering creating a new function from scratch around another library - maybe `LWP::UserAgent`? Would this be best way to go? Are there other libraries better suited to deal with this?

Thanks for any thoughts in advance.

Comment: `$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1)` or `CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_3` if the module is built with a recent `libcurl`.

Comment: That's for >= TTLv1, not for >= 1.2... You want `CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2` for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the line setting `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION`! A default libcurl will try to negotiate the right version anyway so the specific choice is not typically needed nor required.

The number 3 comes from SSLv3 in [this list](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/include/curl/curl.h#L1953) (in a libcurl header file). The first entry is 0, the second 1 etc.

To *explicitly* ask for TLS 1.2 (or later), the symbol to use is `CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2` but I advice against asking for specific versions as long as you don't have to. Note that this symbol was introduced first in libcurl 7.34.0.

Comment: I have no idea why this was downvoted since it is the only correct answer, i.e. don't fiddle with the TLS version at all unless it is needed to work around some broken systems. Additionally one might recommend to remove the lines which disable the certificate validations too (`CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST`, `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`) since otherwise man in the middle attacks get undetected.

Comment: In fact, @SteffenUllrich, the system was "broken" when this code was built. After smashing my head a lot, I found out that the people writing this bit of code didn't actually knew what was being done, so they forced that parameter to make sure we were working on SSLv3.

Comment: This is the correct answer indeed, although there is a bit more to it... I found out the hard way that my Red Hat 7.4 uses by default a very outdated 7.29 `libcurl`. Only from 7.34 and up you can work with TSL 1.2 properly. After updating my `libcurl` and rebuilding my `WWW::Curl::Easy` Perl library, it works like a charm.